# using xslt how to replace the node

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<h:body>
<group id = "1">
<name>xxx</name>
<age>12</age>
<group id = "2">
<name>yyy</name>
<age>13</age>
</h:body>
```

using XSLT i want to replace id=1 with `<group appearance = "field-list">`

Comment: Note that your XML is not [well-formed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document).  I've made the necessary corrections in [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25889556/290085).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), overriding the part you wish to replace with something different.  To wit:

**Given this input XML document:**

```
<h:body xmlns:h="http://example.org/h">
  <group id = "1">
    <name>xxx</name>
    <age>12</age>
  </group>
  <group id = "2">
    <name>yyy</name>
    <age>13</age>
  </group>
</h:body>
```

**This XSLT transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:h="http://example.org/h"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="group[@id = '1']">
    <group appearance = "field-list">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </group>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Will produce this output XML document:**

```
<h:body xmlns:h="http://example.org/h">
  <group appearance="field-list" id="1">
      <name>xxx</name>
      <age>12</age>
  </group>
  <group id="2">
      <name>yyy</name>
      <age>13</age>
  </group>
</h:body>
```